# County-level data on religious affiliation and church attendance in US 1940-1960

Tags: usa, demographics, county, religion, historical

Is there any county-level (or similar) data on religious affiliation and church attendance in the United States from 1940s-1960s?

Comment: here's data from 1952 http://www.usreligioncensus.org/ if you don't have to have 1940-1951.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the FAQ answer to what is available from the U.S. Census Bureau: https://ask.census.gov/prweb/PRServletCustom/YACFBFye-rFIz_FoGtyvDRUGg1Uzu5Mn*/!STANDARD?pyActivity=pyMobileSnapStart&ArticleID=KCP-5050

It suggests that data may exist for the period just before the date range you were hoping for. Perhaps that was what you were trying to extend? [Here's the Pew Foundation's history of the debate](https://www.pewforum.org/2010/01/26/a-brief-history-of-religion-and-the-u-s-census/) surrounding the question of the propriety of the government doing such a survey.

The National Council of Churches has been doing surveys at the county level, but only did one in the time-frame your request. See links at http://www.usreligioncensus.org/ and http://www.thearda.com/Archive/Files/Descriptions/CMS52CNT.asp